# How to pass arguments/parameters when executing bash/shell script from NodeJS

Tags: node.js, bash, shell, parameters, arguments

I have the following code:

```
exec('sh cert-check-script-delete.sh', req.body.deletedCert);
console.log(req.body.deletedCert);
```

The console log correctly shows the `req.body.deletedCert` is non-empty.

And in `cert-check-script-delete.sh` I have:

```
#!/bin/sh

certs.json="./"  # Name of JSON file and directory location
echo -e $1 >> certs.json
```

But it's just writing an empty line to `certs.json`

I've also tried:

```
exec('sh cert-check-script-delete.sh' + req.body.deletedCert)
```

But neither formats work

Comment: BTW, is there a reason you aren't giving your file a proper shebang (`#!/bin/bash`, since `echo -e` isn't safe with `sh`), setting the +x bit, and executing it directly without an explicit interpreter?

Comment: Try adding a space after .sh, exec('sh cert-check-script-delete.sh ' + req.body.deletedCert)

Comment: @DaveCarruthers, that's a huge security risk. Let's say someone submits code saying they want to delete the certificate `$(rm -rf ~)`. You **never, ever, ever** should substitute text from incoming requests into text parsed as part of a shell command.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but writing it in that format is now not even writing the empty line to `certs.json`. Also regarding the shebang, I was not aware there were different types of shebangs and I must've just copied and pasted the shebang from online

Comment: @DaveCarruthers, ...particularly since node [explicitly supports](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html) passing arguments out-of-band; see `child_process.execFile()` and all the other forms with an explicit argument array. Using string concatenation to form a string to run with a shell is dangerous; passing a list of strings as an out-of-band argument is safe.

Comment: @tnoel999888, ...note too that `sh foo.sh` overrides a shebang and always uses the shell `sh`, running your code as a POSIX sh script, not a bash script. If you want to run code with bash, it needs to be invoked with `bash scriptname` -- or, better, by setting permissions and shebang correctly, and running `/path/to/scriptname` and letting that shebang determine the interpreter to use.

Comment: I already read the post you linked this to as a duplicate and that's where I saw the `exec('scriptname.sh' + arg)` format and that didn't work for me

Comment: @tnoel999888 Add the missing space. exec('scriptname.sh ' + arg)

Comment: @DaveCarruthers, ...but, again, it would be a massive security hole if the advice you're giving was followed, making it utterly irresponsible to offer. Even in administrative interfaces, a shell injection attack is still CVE-worthy -- I'm happy to provide links.

Comment: @DaveCarruthers, ...see for example https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2016-9683 -- that's a 9.8 on the CVSSv3 scale and a 10.0 on the CVSSv2 scale, and you're encouraging the OP to create *more* bugs of that type.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy not encouraging anything, just telling the OP why his codes not working, simple as that. Thats how the command hes selected works.

Comment: @DaveCarruthers, yes, but if the OP selects something that's not going to do what they want without huge caveats, a good answer will help them make a more appropriate selection instead. "What they want" surely doesn't include executing commands embedded inside the certificate name -- it's the same reason we don't tell people how to make code with [SQL injections](https://xkcd.com/327/) "work", and instead tell them to use bind variables instead.

Comment: @DaveCarruthers thank you this worked!

Comment: @DaveCarruthers, ...and *that* is **exactly** why bad answers shouldn't be given at all -- we now have one more product with an undetected security bug in the world.

Answer (score 2):

Use `execFile()`, and pass your arguments out-of-band:

```
child_process.execFile('./cert-check-script-delete.sh', [req.body.deletedCert])
```

That way your string (from `req.body.deletedCert`) is passed as a literal argument, not parsed as code. Note that this requires that your script be successfully marked executable (`chmod +x check-cert-script-delete.sh`), and that it start with a valid shebang.

---

If you can't fix your file permissions to make your executable, at least pass the arguments out-of-band:

```
child_process.execFile('/bin/sh', ['./check-cert-script-delete.sh', req.body.deletedCert])
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but where does `child_process` come from? I have the following variable defined `const exec = require('child_process').exec, child;`, is this sufficient or do I need to import anything else too?

Comment: `const child_process = require('child_process')` will get you the whole module, not just one function from it.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but this still doesn't work, I've used the solution involving the space for now

Comment: @tnoel999888, re: "doesn't work" -- it's worth digging into the details. Security matters, and if this doesn't work, it's because something else is broken (your file permissions are wrong, or your shebang is invalid, or so forth).

Comment: @tnoel999888, ...that said, if you **really must** use a shell, at least do it like so: `child_process.execFile('/bin/sh', ['./check-cert-script-delete.sh', req.body.deletedCert])`